# Apache + php-fpm AH01071: Got error 'the log buffer is full (1024). The access log request has been truncated

Tags: php, apache, apache2, fpm

Getting below error for Apache and php environment.

```
apache_error {
    "level":"error",
    "Message":"AH01071: Got error 'the log buffer is full (1024). The access log request has been truncated.'"
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Open /etc/php-fpm.conf and update the value of `log_limit = 4096`or higher if you like, then `systemctl restart php-fpm`.